# How to display keys of Nsdictionary as put?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I am developing an application in which i am putting some keys in dictionary

and displaying it but it is not coming in the order as i have put .

I know it is displaying in arbitrary order but is there any way to control this or any other way.

Please advise me with an example...

Thanks,

Comment: how are you "displaying" your keys? and besides wanting to displaying them, what are you really trying to do here?  is NSDictionary really what you want to use?

Comment: i just want to display it like the way i am putting the keys in it with the function initWithObjectsAndKeys:.........i want to put array as objects for different keya in tableview and display sections names as keys but display in the way like the keys are put.and then if a particular key is pressed the object which is an array will display the values...

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary entries are not ordered. If you want to order them you could add a custom `sortIndex` to each stored object. Use this custom integer to order the array returned using:

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
```

Comment: sorry i think i have asked for an example .Can you please provide me an example based on my question please....

Comment: No, I suggest you read up on some programming basics and then come back to this problem :).